# GeoServer - OGC API Features - API Definition

Tags: geoserver, ogc, license, ogc-api-features

I'm using GeoServer 2.24 in combination with the corresponding OGC API module.

I need to specify the API use conditions (license CC BY 4.0) and I don't know where to insert it in the administration console.

In the OpenAPI Specification exists the Info Object with the attribute 'license':

[image]

However, in the API Definition document (JSON) that GeoServer creates, this attribute doesn't exists.

[image]

Is there a way to insert the 'license'?

Comment: can you set it in the GUI?

Comment: Do you mean Geoserver GUI? 
https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/gettingstarted/web-admin-quickstart/index.html

Comment: Yes, the GeoServer GUI (I assume the API stuff has a GUI?) once it is filled in it will probably show up in the REST response. Other wise you'll need to look at the code

Comment: Ok, yes, Geoserver GUI has  configuration options for the API. But I don't find the configuration for the license.
The API Feature is an extra module to Geoserver and this is the to configure it:
https://docs.geoserver.org/main/en/user/community/ogc-api/features/index.html
Reading this I get to the Service Metadata options where I can set the 'access constrains', which is what I need. But when I set it, the API definition document doesn't update

Comment: Sounds like you need to enhance the code then.

Comment: Probably, in the end the license attribute is not mandatory in the OpenAPI Specification. Thank you for your help